# Create a Vector and store information within a Recursive Method in Java

Tags: java, recursion, vector

**EDIT**
Someone has pointed out to me that effectively I need to step down through all of my recursion to make sure I hit the end point, and then start gathering values when I go back through the stacks. I have no idea what this means.

My goal is to build a recursive method to build a path through a maze, store that path in a Vector, and return it at the end of my recursion.

My method runs the maze, but I am having difficulties storing the list in my Vector because I need to instantiate it every recursion.

Here is my code(**EDITED**):

```
protected Vector<GameCell> findPath(int nRow, int nCol)
{

    aBoard[nRow][nCol].setVisited(true);
    if(aBoard[nRow][nCol].getVal() == 'E')
    {
        Vector<GameCell> list = new Vector<GameCell>();
        list.add(aBoard[nRow][nCol]);
        return list;
    }


    if(canGoLeft(nRow, nCol))
    {
        if(!aBoard[nRow][nCol - 1].isVisited())
        {

            return findPath(nRow, --nCol);
        }
    }

    if(canGoRight(nRow, nCol))
    {
        if(!aBoard[nRow][nCol+1].isVisited())
        {
            return findPath(nRow, ++nCol);
        }

    }

    if(canGoUp(nRow, nCol))
    {
        if(!aBoard[nRow - 1][nCol].isVisited())
        {
            return findPath(--nRow, nCol);
        }
    }

    if(canGoDown(nRow, nCol))
    {
        if(!aBoard[nRow + 1][nCol].isVisited())
        {
            return findPath(++nRow, nCol);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("You hit a dead end.");
    return null;

}
```

Is there a way I can not instantiate my Vector every recursion so I can store my values permanently?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes. Pass it as argument to the method, and create it out of the method.

Comment: I should clarify, the parameters I have set are the only ones I can use as per my specification. My Vector must be created in this method.

Comment: `java.util.Vector` has been obsolete for 19 years. How long have you been programming in Java?

Comment: Not long, it was a spec required in our program. Our instructor has been programming for far longer than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to add elements to my list after I had found my path on my way back up the stack of recursion. Here is the solution. I still have a bug in it but the problem I asked about is fixed.

```
protected Vector<GameCell> findPath(int nRow, int nCol)
{
    this.aBoard[nRow][nCol].setVisited(true);        
    if(this.aBoard[nRow][nCol].getVal() == 'E')
    {
        Vector<GameCell> list = new Vector<GameCell>();
        list.add(this.aBoard[nRow][nCol]);
        return list;  
    }

    if(canGoUp(nRow, nCol))
    {
        if(!this.aBoard[nRow - 1][nCol].isVisited())
        {
            Vector<GameCell> list = findPath(nRow - 1, nCol);
            if(list != null)
            {
                list.add(this.aBoard[nRow][nCol]);
                return list;
            }
        }
    }

    if(canGoRight(nRow, nCol))
    {
        if(!this.aBoard[nRow][nCol+1].isVisited())
        {
            Vector<GameCell> list = findPath(nRow, nCol + 1);
            if(list != null)
            {
                list.add(this.aBoard[nRow][nCol]);
                return list;
            }
        }

    }

    if(canGoLeft(nRow, nCol))
    {
        if(!this.aBoard[nRow][nCol - 1].isVisited())
        {
            Vector<GameCell> list = findPath(nRow, nCol - 1);
            if(list != null)
            {
                list.add(this.aBoard[nRow][nCol]);
                return list;

            }
        }
    }

    if(canGoDown(nRow, nCol))
    {
        if(!this.aBoard[nRow + 1][nCol].isVisited())
        {
            Vector<GameCell> list = findPath(nRow + 1, nCol);
            if(list != null)
            {
                list.add(this.aBoard[nRow][nCol]);
                return list;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;

}
```

Comment: Fixed the last bug and everything works now. Where I have pre-increment and decrements in my nested if statements I should have had + or - 1 instead.

Not --nRow, but nRow - 1. Recursion was returning to them after returning null and returning null on 2 values in my list instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way of doing it is to delegate to another method that is the recursive one and takes the list to fill as argument:

```
public List<GameCell> findPath(int nRow, int nCol) {
    List<GameCell> result = new ArrayList<>();
    doFindPathRecursively(result, nRow, nCol);
    return result;
}

private void doFindPathRecursively(List<GameCell> result, int nRow, int nCol) {
    ...
}
```

Note that Vector is effectively deprecated since Java 2, hence the use of List and ArrayList instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use outside methods to do that; otherwise, this would be a much easier assignment. I have updated my question to make it more clear as to what I require.

Comment: This looks like an arbitrary, unrealistic requirement. But you can also return create and return a List at each call, and append the returned list to the current one, to achieve the same effect.

Comment: It seems consistent that a teacher who still uses `Vector` would hand out assignments with arbitrary and unrealistic requirements...